# format day hour minute second column in r

Tags: r

I have a data frame with column name anticipation:

```
df = data.frame(anticipation = c('1d0s','1d5h49m6s','5h39m','8h9s')
```

and I want to arrange the anticipation column into `%d %h %m %s` format. the expected output is as follows:

```
output
1d 0h 0m 0s
1d 5h 49m 6s
0d 5h 39m 0s
0d 8h 0m 9s
```

I have tried doing this manually like this:

```
    df$Anticipation.day = as.numeric(as.character(data.frame(str_split_fixed(df$anticipation, "d", 2))$X1))
and so on
```

but it is becoming very complex. Any help will be highly appreciated. TIA.

Comment: Please provide the desired output as text. It is unreadable in dark mode.

Comment: It's also unreadable to screen readers. Also, when you have the data in a textual format, please don't assume that we will spend our time transcribing your picture into something usable just because you wanted an easy way to ask the question.

Comment: Sorry for that, I have modified the queries. I hope it will work.

Answer (score 1):

```r
time2num <- function(x, mult = c(24*60*60, 60*60, 60, 1)) {
  vapply(strsplit(x, "\\D+"), function(z) sum(as.numeric(z) * tail(mult, n = length(z))), numeric(1))
}

vec <- c("1d 5h 49m 6s", "0d 5h 39m 0s")
time2num(vec)
# [1] 107346  20340
```